# How to properly make a bootable iso from the contents of a directory

Tags: usb, iso

I wanted to have a customized Ubuntu Live CD so:

I mounted  `ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso`.

Copied its content to a directory in my home folder.

Used `unsquashfs filesystem.squashfs` to extract the file system.

Used `chroot` to change the root into the extracted file system.

Uninstalled some packages I didn't need.

Used `sudo mksquashfs squashfs-root filesystem.squashfs -b 1048576 -comp xz -Xdict-size 100%` to pack the modified file system back into `filesystem.squashfs`.

Replaced the original `filesystem.squashfs` I extracted with the modified one.

Used `genisoimage -r -V "Ubuntu" -cache-inodes -J -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o ironpig.iso FC5/` to build a `.iso` (FC5 being the directory I extracted `ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso` into).

But after burning `ironpig.iso` into a SD card with Etcher it looks like this:

[image]

But I get this by burning the original `ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso`:

[image]

How can I make my`.iso` bootable?

Answer (score 0):

A cd typically uses iso9660 on the raw media and through the spec uses El Torito (an emulated floppy drive with a drive image) for booting along with UEFI which requires an EFI executable at /EFI/boot/bootx64.efi. The emulated floppy image is also for UEFI formated FAT32 containing the same /EFI/boot/bootx64.efi but also contains a legacy boot loader at the beginning of the image.

Comment: Other arrangements are possible like for example a GPT partitioned CD containing an ESP.